# visualforce selectRadio --- how to get reference via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex-code

I have radio button control and from my Javascript, I'm trying to get the array of radio input via javascript `getElementsByName()`

The first alert: `alert(radioTitleDisplay);`

returns `[object HTMLCollection]`

The second alert however, does not fire. And Firebug reports

```
radioTitleDisplay.options is null.
```

How can I get access to the radio button. Am I missing something? (I could assign id to each tag from root to childs but I don't want to do that since if I change the structure, I have to change the id too which is not rubust.)

```
<apex:form >
   <apex:selectRadio value="{!titleDisplay}" id="titleDisplayRadio">
       <apex:selectOption itemValue="0" itemLabel="one"  />
       <apex:selectOption itemValue="1" itemLabel="two"  />
       <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="three"  />

       <script type="text/javascript">

          var radioTitleDisplay = document.getElementsByName('{!$Component.titleDisplayRadio}');

          alert(radioTitleDisplay);
          alert(radioTitleDisplay.options);                                     
       </script>
    </apex:selectRadio>
</apex:form>
```

The rendered visualforce page, one of input tag is:

```
<input type="radio" value="2" id="thePage:j_id27:titleDisplayRadio:2" 
name="thePage:j_id27:titleDisplayRadio">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion, use jQuery. Helps immensely, especially for digging through iterative and other lists.

What you did here is get a list of input html objects, that list has no options property. HTML DOM radio buttons are disconnected, there is no central object that holds them all.

EDIT: This code will for example alert you the the selected radio button:

```
var myradios = document.getElementsByName('{!$Component.myRadio}');
for(i = 0; i < myradios.length; i++) 
    if(myradios[i].checked) {
        // now we now the selected index
        alert('Selected value is: ' + myradios[i].value);
    }
```

Comment: I agree, but the problem is that the SF modifies the element's Id so it's like being generated dynamically and use of $Component approach seems not working for me as described above. I can get reference to the element if it is just simple variable. In case of array like above, I can't really figure how to get reference.

Comment: Yes, it does, but is reflected in the $Component output. Everything is ok with your code, you just need to realize that a set of <input type=radio> elements is not a single DOM object, you will always get a collection. Any operation you want to do in JS has to be done over the collection elements, its how html dom operates, nothing to do with salesforce.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Could you provide sample code? I'm still not clear why my approach is not working.

Comment: I updated the post with a code sample to determine selected radio button.